# How to make the dots have matching colors to their raincloud plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, colors

When using different formulas to create my raincloud plot, I noticed that the dots are just gray, instead of matching to their plot. How can I change this?

After searching around i finally learned how to change the color of all the dots, but not by group.

Here is code you can use to see what I mean:

```
    iris %>%
      group_by(Species) %>%
      mutate(mean = mean(Petal.Length),
             se = sd(Petal.Length)/sqrt(length(Petal.Length))) %>%
      ungroup() %>%
      ggplot(aes(x=Petal.Length, y=Species)) +
      stat_slab(aes(fill = Species)) +
      stat_dots(side = "bottom", shape = 16, colour="black") + 
      scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
      stat_summary(fun= "mean", geom= "point", colour= "black", 
                   position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)) +
      theme_bw() +
      theme(legend.position = "top")+
      # scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-4.5, .5), breaks = seq(-4.5, 0.5, by = 0.5)) +
      labs(title="Raincloud plot with ggdist")
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the same colors for the dot plots as for the densities you have to map on the `color` aes in `stat_dots` and set the same color palette for which I added `aesthetics = c("fill", "color")` to `scale_fill_brewer`.

Using some fake random example data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggdist)

set.seed(123)

uniquePeople <- data.frame(
  ageGroup = sample(c("18-37", "38-57", "50-82"), 500, replace = TRUE),
  thresh = runif(500, -4.5, .5)
)

uniquePeople %>%
  dplyr::group_by(ageGroup) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    mean = mean(thresh),
    se = sd(thresh) / sqrt(length(thresh))
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = thresh, y = ageGroup, group = ageGroup)) +
  stat_slab(aes(fill = ageGroup), scale = 0.5) +
  stat_dots(aes(color = ageGroup), side = "bottom", shape = 16) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1", aesthetics = c("fill", "color")) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(
    xmin = mean
    - 1.96 * se,
    xmax = mean + 1.96 * se
  ), width = 0.2) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "point", shape = 16, size = 3.5) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 16) +
  theme(legend.position = "top") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-4.5, .5), breaks = seq(-4.5, 0.5,
    by =
      0.5
  )) +
  labs(title = "Raincloud plot with ggdist")
```

[image]